Crontab command to open YouTube URL
My goal is to open a YouTube channel page with crontab. I have used this command:
30 14 * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && firefox --new-window https://www.youtube.com/channelurl
The Channel Page of YouTube opens, but with no audio. If I manually open the YouTube channel without crontab audio is OK, but my goal is to open the YouTube page with normal audio automatically with crontab.
Thanks
Paolo

DISPLAY on its own may be insufficient - you may need to set other environment variables such as DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS and/or XDG_RUNTIME_DIR. See for example No sound from crontab running my custom script

Hi Steeldriver, thanks for suggestions: I will try and keep you informed.

So my DISPLAY command how would it change?
